# Maintain an open session using request

Tags: node.js, node-request

I'm pretty new to this...

I have the following code:

```
request("http://somePythonServer.com?param1=1&param2=2", function (err, response, body) {
      if (err){
         console.error(err);
         next(err);
      }
      console.log("Response Ended - SUCCESS");
});
```

This request is made each time with different parameters and values and currently a new connection is being opened each time i run it.

My question is how to maintain an open connection?

EDIT: I have control on both sending and receiving end of the request.

MY GOAL: 
I'm trying to boost speed between two servers (NodeJS is sending HTTP GET to a python simple HTTP server) I want the connection between those two to remain open at all time in order for the requests to be as fast as possible.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve when you say "how to maintain an open connection"?   You just call `request()` and the connection is opened for you automatically so it's no extra work for you so I don't know what problem you're really trying to solve?

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm trying to boost speed between two servers (NodeJS is sending HTTP GET to a python simple HTTP server)
I want the connection between those two to remain open at all time.

Comment: @TBE Maybe really late but I think you should look into WebSockets.

Comment: Set the Keep Alive Header